# Explicit Registrations of handler mappings

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, handler

I was going through spring documentation more specifically handler mapping section and came to know that we can register the handler mapping method at runtime. I understand how it is done but the thing that I am not able to grasp is why do we need such functionality in the first place?

Please refer following code snippet for registering handlers.

```
@Autowired
  public void setHandlerMapping(RequestMappingHandlerMapping mapping, HelloRestController handler) 
        throws NoSuchMethodException {

    RequestMappingInfo info = RequestMappingInfo
            .paths("/mycustomapi").methods(RequestMethod.GET).build(); 
    Method method = HelloRestController.class.getMethod("customHandler"); 
    mapping.registerMapping(info, handler, method); 
}
```

[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-controller)

If someone can explain some use cases where it required then it will be helpful thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have never used this, but here is one utility I can think of :

As annotations only accept constant expression as parameters, you can't write something like that :

```java
@GetMapping(requestMapping(...)) // The value for annotation GetMapping.value must be a constant expression
public String customHandler(...) {
 ...
}
```

But you could write that :

```java
RequestMappingInfo info = RequestMappingInfo
    .paths(requestMapping(...))
    .methods(RequestMethod.GET)
    .build();
```

In oher words, you could write handlers for URI that are calculated (stored in a configuration file for example).